# yfinance - Setting my end date to 2021-1-1 but the end date for the data becomes today date

Tags: python, yfinance

For yfinance python module, I set my end date to **2021-1-1** but the it turns out to be today date. How to fix it?

`yfinance.download(tickers="AAPL",end="2021-1-1",period="5y",interval="1d")`

Results:
[image]

Comment: Checking the program source, if no start date is given, the default value 1970-01-01 will be given, and if no start date is given, it will be taken by the acquisition period, I guess. The source can be found [here](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/main/yfinance/base.py).

Answer (score 1):

I found that when you use `period="5y"`, whatever **start/end** date mentioned is not working

dropping the period parameter, you can try **datetime format** to set **start** and **end** date for 5years as following

```
import yfinance
import datetime as dt

enddate = dt.datetime.strptime("2021-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d").date()
startdate = enddate - dt.timedelta(days=365*5) # for 5 years

data = yfinance.download(tickers="AAPL", start=startdate, end=enddate, interval="1d")
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close     Volume
Date
2016-01-04   25.652500   26.342501   25.500000   26.337500   24.323219  270597600
2016-01-05   26.437500   26.462500   25.602501   25.677500   23.713696  223164000
2016-01-06   25.139999   25.592501   24.967501   25.174999   23.249626  273829600
2016-01-07   24.670000   25.032499   24.107500   24.112499   22.268383  324377600
2016-01-08   24.637501   24.777500   24.190001   24.240000   22.386133  283192000
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...        ...
2020-12-24  131.320007  133.460007  131.100006  131.970001  131.549637   54930100
2020-12-28  133.990005  137.339996  133.509995  136.690002  136.254608  124486200
2020-12-29  138.050003  138.789993  134.339996  134.869995  134.440399  121047300
2020-12-30  135.580002  135.990005  133.399994  133.720001  133.294067   96452100
2020-12-31  134.080002  134.740005  131.720001  132.690002  132.267349   99116600

[1259 rows x 6 columns]
```

## OR

mention the start and end date using str date as following

```
import yfinance
data = yfinance.download(tickers="AAPL", start="2016-01-03", end="2021-01-01", interval="1d")
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close     Volume
Date
2016-01-04   25.652500   26.342501   25.500000   26.337500   24.323219  270597600
2016-01-05   26.437500   26.462500   25.602501   25.677500   23.713696  223164000
2016-01-06   25.139999   25.592501   24.967501   25.174999   23.249626  273829600
2016-01-07   24.670000   25.032499   24.107500   24.112499   22.268383  324377600
2016-01-08   24.637501   24.777500   24.190001   24.240000   22.386133  283192000
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...        ...
2020-12-24  131.320007  133.460007  131.100006  131.970001  131.549637   54930100
2020-12-28  133.990005  137.339996  133.509995  136.690002  136.254608  124486200
2020-12-29  138.050003  138.789993  134.339996  134.869995  134.440399  121047300
2020-12-30  135.580002  135.990005  133.399994  133.720001  133.294067   96452100
2020-12-31  134.080002  134.740005  131.720001  132.690002  132.267349   99116600

[1259 rows x 6 columns]
```